# App Crash on Android Tablet - use of CN1Libs-NativeLogsReader

Tags: codenameone

After using sometime App crash on User Device which I don't have access to it. I have read the blog about using the CN1Libs-NativeLogsReader to see the error occurred on remote devices. I would need some help on how to use it for this kind of issue for debug builds. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

That won't save you from a crash as that would be too late in the game.

You can use the API to get the native log but you can't use it to catch a physical crash.

Comment: In that case what would be option to find the cause for physical crash? Please advise.

Comment: If you have a pro account the crash protection might catch that although it's unclear if it will. This highly depends on the cause https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---use-crash-protection-get-device-logs.html
If you have physical access to the device you can try debugging on it using a cable https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---use-the-include-sources-feature-to-debug-the-native-code-on-iosandroid-etc.html
The last option is trial and error through elimination, trying to narrow down the specific region that causes the crash and slowly commenting in/out pieces of functionality